# How to add custom fields dynamically to the form before submit with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, codeigniter

I have copied the jQuery but I have no idea how to manage it. i tried many ways to do it, tried a couple of more codes too.

```js
var rowNum = 0;
function addRow(frm) {
    rowNum ++;
    var row = '<p id="rowNum' + rowNum + '"><?= form_input('Day#', '+frm.day_no.value+', 'placeholder="Day#"')?>
     <?= form_input('Day#', '+frm.description.value+', 'placeholder="Day#"')?> 
     <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+');">
     </p>';
    jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
    frm.day_no.value = '';
    frm.description.value = '';
}

function removeRow(rnum) {
    jQuery('#rowNum'+rnum).remove();
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <label><?= form_input('Day#', '', 'placeholder="Day#"')?></label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label><?= form_input('Description', '', 'placeholder="Description"')?></label>
  </li>
  <label>
    <input type="button" value="add field" name="add field"> 
  </label>
</ul>
```

i tried this one too: like this i have tried a couple of more codes i have checked for the errors but as i am new so its hard to figure out whats going on with it.

```
<div class="col-md-4 publish">
    <h4>Day Plan</h4>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <ul>
        <div class="items">
        <div class="form-group">
        <li><label><input id="day_no" class="form-control" name="day_no" 
         required="required" type="NUMBER" placeholder="Day #" /></li>
            <li><label><input id="description" class="form-control" 
            name="description" required="required" type="TEXTAREA" 
            placeholder="Description" /></label></li></div>
            <label><button type="button" class="add_field_button">Add 
            Field</button> </label>
        </div>

        <script 
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var max_fields = 20;
                var wrapper = $("#items");
                var add_button = $(".add_field_button");

                //var x = 2;
                $(add_button).click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if(x < max_fields){
                        x++;
                        $(wrapper).append(' <ul>
                            <div class="form-group">
                            '<li><label><input id="day_no" class="form-
                            control" name="day_no" required="required" 
                            type="NUMBER" placeholder="Day #" /></label>
                            </li>'
                            '<li><label><input id="description" 
                             class="form-control" name="description" 
                              required="required" type="TEXTAREA" 
                              placeholder="Description" /></label></li>' +
                              '<a href="#" class="remove_field"><i class="fa 
                              fa-times"></a></div></ul>'
                    );

                    }
                });

                $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){
                    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
                })
            });
        </script>

    </ul>
```

[this is the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZuga.png)

Comment: You want to repeat the fields dynamically right ??

Comment: yes i want to repeat the fields, like there are days plane section which includes day# and description. so i want to repeat both of them with jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried this and it worked for me.

```
            <div class="input-group control-group after-add-more">


                <label><input type="text" name="dayplans[title][]" class="form-control" placeholder="DAY #"></label>
                <label><textarea name="dayplans[description][]" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" style="margin: 0px; width: 196px; height: 56px;"></textarea></label>
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-success add-more" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Copy Fields-These are the fields which we get through jquery and then add after the above input,-->
            <div class="copy-fields" style="display: none">
                <div class="control-group input-group" style="">
                    <label><input type="text" name="dayplans[title][]" class="form-control" placeholder="DAY #"></label>
                    <label><textarea name="dayplans[description][]" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" style="margin: 0px; width: 196px; height: 56px;"></textarea></label>
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Remove</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

            //here first get the contents of the div with name class copy-fields and add it to after "after-add-more" div class.
            $(".add-more").click(function(){
                var html = $(".copy-fields").html();
                $(".after-add-more").after(html);
            });
//here it will remove the current value of the remove button which has been pressed
            $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){
                $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
            });

        });
</script>
```